# While debugging Java cucucmber feature file from eclipse debugging doesn't go smooth.Break points are not high lighting

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java

I am using cucumber with java and using Spring tool set. When I go for debugging a feature file.(login.feature)
Execution stop at break point suppose where break point is applied in base.java class but current focus remains on feature file that was login.feature and if i open base class manually then also break point line is not highlighted.

Also suppose the next break point is in some other class like util.java then also eclipse doesn't move its focus to Util class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't set break point in feature file. only set in the java file

Comment: Yes I have put debug points in java class not feature file but still the debugging behavior is same as i mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience. I use JUnit and got debugging to work by creating a new JUnit debug configuration. I set the project name, test class (name of the package and class containing the test runner), and set Test runner to JUnit 4(Will not work with Junit 3). This works fine - breakpoints are highlighted as I step through the code and I can see which steps are successful in the JUnit output tab.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the maven project you have created and select debug as Java Application and select main-io.cucumber.core.cli.  You will be able to see the breakpoints in debug window as below